# cant access website thru www only works on direct xyz.com

Tags: htaccess, server, dns

i have recently migrated my website to kinsta. the site is not loading when you enter `https://www.example.com` with the domain, but loads well on `https://example.com`

[image]

please give some pointers to resolve this issue.
thanks in advance

Comment: Not really a wordpress issue...but there could be several reasons for this.  The most likely is that you didn't set up your DNS correctly at the registrar for top level and www to go to your hosting.  You need to get in touch with them to get the issue resolved.

Comment: it turned out to be the DNS configuration just like you said. many thanks @rudtek!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if anyone got stuck with this same issue, it turned out for me that i need to add a `type A` record with Name `www` and Value `server ip address` on the DNS configuration
thanks @rudtek for pointing it out!